# Cross-Compiling XZ-5.X.X on Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-platform, xz

I am tring to cross compile [xz-5.0.4](http://tukaani.org/xz/) on Windows. I have folowed the instruction in the [INSTALL-Windows.txt](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/xz/windows/INSTALL-Windows.txt) but I receive an error

```
Initializing Automake:
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/c/devel/xz-5.0.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Can someone help me find the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You have problems with your gcc: configure can not pass simple test with compiling void file.

Install GCC as described in your document, next make sure, that its binary is called `gcc` (usually windows distrs prefer something like gcc-4.4), if no -- make symlink. Also make sure it is in PATH.

Try command `gcc test.c` from command line where test.c is file with contents like `int main(void) { return 0; }` -- this is how configure usually checks compiler. If it doesn't work, make it work, next configure again.